# Iteration Functionality

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iterator, iteration

Below is the simple programme which I wrote in Python

```
Animal = ['tiger','lion','dog','cat']
xyz = iter(Animal)
print(next(xyz))
```

The output was

```
tiger
```

Now I read that `iter()` method points towards the first element of iterable i.e `'tiger'`, so the second line will make `xyz` pointing towards `'tiger'` & then in third line when I use `next` it should go to `'lion'` and print that why is it not doing so?

I know there is some conceptual mistake which I am doing & I am even not able to comprehend that whether `xyz` or iterators are variable object or something else. Can anyone please elaborate?

Comment: What do you mean by "variable object or something else"? Python technically doesn't have variables, it has identifiers (names) that point to objects (values). See [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: "Now I read that iter() method points towards the first element of iterable i.e 'tiger'," no, that doesn't sound correct. Simply put, `iter` returns *an iterator* from an iterable.

Answer (score 1):

You are slightly confused.

Think of `next()` as "give the current value and then move the pointer to the next item."  Line numbers have nothing to do with it.   The next time you called `next(xyz)`, you'd get `'lion'` no matter where it occurs.

Comment: I don't think they mean line numbers

Answer (score 1):

[`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) doesn't "point towards the first element of the iterable", it just returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator).

```
>>> xyz
<list_iterator object at 0x7f56c61eb3c8>
```

You could, for example, turn it back into a list:

```
>>> xyz = iter(Animal)
>>> list(xyz)
['tiger', 'lion', 'dog', 'cat']
```

But unlike a list, it can only be consumed once.

```
>>> list(xyz)
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter) and [`next`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#next) do exactly what the docs say they do, so this code:

```
Animal = ['tiger','lion','dog','cat']
xyz = iter(Animal)
for i in range(len(Animal) + 1):
    print(next(xyz))
```

prints all animals from first to last until the iterator is exhausted:

```
tiger
lion
dog
cat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(next(xyz))
StopIteration
```